# How to run shell script as postgres on remote server using fabric python

Tags: python, postgresql, shell, fabric

How can I enter postgres sudo user to run a script in a specific folder?
The reason I have to cd into the script is because it requires me to run it in that particular directory.

Would love inputs and comments on my approach and see if there is a better way.

The following is the fabric script I came up with. but it does't allow me to enter postgres user mode.

```
@task
def run():
    with sudo('-su postgres'):
        with cd('/home/XXX/www/my_app'):
            run('somescript.sh', use_sudo=True)
```

Thank you!

Comment: run('somescript.sh', use_sudo=True) will use root again, I guess

Comment: But I need to be a postgres user... not root.

Answer (score 0):

[doc of sudo command](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo)

So you can switch user with sudo command like following:

`sudo("mkdir /var/www/new_docroot", user="www-data")`

Comment: changing the user to postgres in sudo isn't allowed. so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `sudo: unable to resolve host guest.localdomain`

Comment: check http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none